# Docusign: I don't see "users and groups" in my admin page

Tags: docusignapi

i have adocusign admin account: basic api plan, and i want to add new users.
In the test account i have a menu: Users and Groups which allow us to manage users but in the live account i can't find this menu.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Basic API plan is a single-user account. You'll need to upgrade to a higher level of plan in order to gain access to the Users and Groups section in DocuSign Admin.

If you're not sure which level of account would be right for you, I'd recommend contacting the DocuSign Sales team: https://www.docusign.com/contact-sales